# How to share Facebook analytics with another Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, analytics

I already setup Facebook Analytics for web site and can see visit count and other stats for web site.

How I can permit access for other Facebook users to this Analytic page? And which link they should use for access?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. For Facebook end user support, please consult their Help section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytics are tied to an App. Add users to the App role - there is even a specific role for Analytics:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[App-ID]/roles/

Comment: Yes, i try to do this, users were added but in "pending" state. Who should approve them?

Comment: well...they should ;)